# Achievement for consuming tagged item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to make and achivement for eating a tagged type of food, found in other loot tables, except neither of them are loading (The loot tables are empty when i open them). For the loot table I have:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:chest",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": {
        "type": "minecraft:uniform",
        "min": 2,
        "max": 3
      },
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 15,
          "name": "minecraft:bread",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_nbt",
              "tag": "{CustomModelData:42,MoldyBread:1b,display:{Name:'[{\"text\":\"Moldy Bread\",\"italic\":false}]'}}"
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 1,
                "max": 4
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 10,
          "name": "minecraft:bread",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 1,
                "max": 4
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And for my achievement I have

```
{
  "__comment": "By Aceplante",
  "criteria": {
    "moldybread": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:consume_item",
      "conditions": {
        "item": {
          "items": [
            "minecraft:bread"
          ],
          "nbt": "{tag:{MoldyBread:1b}}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rewards": {
    "function": "minecraft:achv_moldybread"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I did not receive an answer, I ended up figuring this out on my own:

For the achievement:

```
{
  "__comment": "By Aceplante",
  "criteria": {
    "moldybread": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:consume_item",
      "conditions": {
        "item": {
          "items": [
            "minecraft:bread"
          ],
          "nbt": "{MoldyBread:1b}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rewards": {
    "function": "minecraft:achv_moldybread"
  }
}
```

And for the loot table:

```
{
      "rolls": {
        "min": 3,
        "max": 4,
        "type": "minecraft:uniform"
      },
      "bonus_rolls": 0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 15,
          "name": "minecraft:bread",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_name",
              "name": {
                "text": "Moldy Bread",
                "italic": false
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_nbt",
              "tag": "{CustomModelData:42,MoldyBread:1b}"
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "type": "minecraft:uniform",
                "min": 3,
                "max": 8
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "weight": 8,
          "name": "minecraft:bread",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 2,
                "max": 6,
                "type": "minecraft:uniform"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```